# How to get a meaningful function signature from anything callable

Tags: c++, function, template-meta-programming

Consider such a beast:

```
template<typename Func>
void register_function(Func func) {
  // type-erase Func and pass it on to some other function
}
```

Assume that this can be passed anything callable.

I know how to get at the function's signature if `Func` is a plain function type. Given that `func` could be a plain function, a `std::function<F>`, or a function object (a `std::bind()` expression), how can I get at the function's arguments?

***Note:***

- in this case, the functions only ever have either zero, one, or two arguments
- if it's a function object, it's the result of `std::bind()`
- the signature is needed in order to get at the argument's types, which need to be usable in the type-erased thing passed on
- this is strictly ***C++03*** (embedded platform), so no variable template arguments etc.

Comment: Sorry, but this is impossible in the general case. You should know know, at registration site, what kinds of arguments you're going to pass to the callback.

Comment: If it's strictly C++03, then you can't get a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object.

Comment: boost::function or std::tr1::function serve the same purpose.

Comment: As in maybe partial templates with embedded names?

Comment: I think you can't recurse on F's arguments.

Comment: @Joachim: `std::tr1::function()` was codified in TR1, which was published in C++03.

Comment: But your question uses `std::`, not `std::tr1::`...

Comment: But `std::tr1` is not `std`, and it's *not* published as a part of the C++03 standard, but as an extension of it (therefore the need of a new namespace).

Comment: @Joachim: And your point is?

Comment: The point is, that if you're using extensions then you're not *strict*. And unless you're mandated by company policy, is there anything stopping you from updating the compiler to one that can handle C++11 (or C++14 now that it's been approved)? Or use Boost, which much of the library changes for C++11/14 are based on?

Comment: However, regarding your question about getting arguments or anything else from the template argument, since C++ have no introspection it's simply impossible.

Comment: @Angew: I learned in previous questions that people are used to `std::function` and choke on `std::tr1::function`. (But then some smart ass comes along and points out that, literally, this is wrong. It seems I can't win this game...)

Comment: @Joachim: ___1)___ There's no more modern C++ compiler for the embedded platform I am on. ___2)___ Keep counting beans if you want. Meanwhile, we have C++03, TR1, and boost 1.52 available. ___3)___ Of course you can deduce function arguments from a function passed in as template argument at compile-time. I know how to do that. I just don't know how to do this when anything callable can be passed.

Comment: @sbi: You could start simplifying the problem you are facing by overloading your function; get the deduction on for simple functions and `std::function` since those are readily accessibly, and then your problem is reduced to getting it for the result of `std::bind` (hint: you lose). Note the availability of [`function_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html)

Comment: @Matthieu: Thanks, `function_traits` is exactly what I did for plain functions a decade ago, and what I expected by now to already exist. That leaves the problem of `std::function<>` (which might, through clever overloading, be reducible to `std::function<F>`, with `F` being crackable by `function_traits`). That leaves `bind()`. `:(`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Impossible. A function object can have overloaded or templated `operator()`. Thus the idea of it having "a signature" simply doesn't apply, because it can have an unbounded number of signatures.

If you restrict it to only having one signature, then you can take the address of operator() and then get the arguments from the member function pointer type using regular template specialization.

Comment: OK, I hadn't thought of functors with overloaded `operator()`. It doesn't apply here, though. If it's a functor, it's the result of `std::bind()` and there's just one overload.

Comment: `std::bind` produces templated `operator()`s.

Comment: Yes, and I didn't have an idea how to deduce those, nor how to discriminate between all the possibilities in order to use the correct mechanism to crack the signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you know at *runtime* the signature of some called (plain) function, you could use (on Linux notably) the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) to call it.

If you don't even know at runtime the signature of the function to call, it is impossible, since in general the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions will dictate different ways of passing function arguments according to their type.

For instance, the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) (followed on most Linux 64 bits x86-64 systems) requires that floating point values and integral values are passed in different set of registers.

See for example the [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) wikipage.

Comment: I was mentioning type erasure. For this, I need the types at compile-time. Conveniently, I also have them available at compile-time, since they're embedded in the signature of `F`. I only need to crack that `F`. At compile-time.